# Where/How to use a development log with Meteor.js

Tags: logging, meteor

In the Rails world I'm used to having a development log that I can use to review the underpinnings of every "transaction" in detail as I'm building the app.

I've searched through the system logs but have not found any meteor log files for the app I'm working on which means that there isn't one there or I'm just not seeing it. *(Of course, I have been accused of being blind.)*

In Meteor is there a place where all transactions are stored when working in the development environment? Or if not is there a library anyone can suggest for gaining this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following package from atmosphere seems like it'll fit your specifications. It's called `Pince`.

Link: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/pince

Comment: Thanks much. Looks like this might do it. I'll try this out and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Looks like that package moved: [github](https://github.com/mad-eye/pince)